# Rewrite the following 2nd order linear differential equation as a linear system in the form y'=Ay.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question: Rewrite the following 2nd order linear differential equation as a linear system in the form y'=Ay. Solve both the original DE and the linear system you derived. How do the two solutions compare?**

**${2y''+3y'-6y=0}$**

> Here's what I have done so far:
>
> ${2y''+3y'-6y=0}$
>
> $y''+ \frac{3y'}{2} - 3y = 0$
>
> Changed the formula to this
>
> $r^2+ \frac{3r}{2} - 3 = 0$
>
> Found the zeros to be
>
> $Ae^{\sqrt(57)/2 -3/4} + Be^{-\sqrt(57)/2 -3/4} = y$
>
> I used the wolfram calculator to check, and apparantly my answer is
>   correct but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be checking my solution
>   with? Thanks so much for any and all help.

Comment: by the way, I'm sorry if the mathjax looks weird, I've only recently starting using it. Trying to take yalls advice :-)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Here is an example using `\sqrt`: To get $\sqrt{\frac{ab}{\sqrt{2}}-x}$, use `\sqrt{\frac{ab}{\sqrt{2}}-x}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this as a system of equations

$y'' = 3y - \frac 32 y'\\
y'=x\\
x' = 3y - \frac 32 x$

$\begin{bmatrix} {x\\y}\end{bmatrix}'
 = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac 32&3\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbf x' = A \mathbf x\\
\mathbf x = e^{At}\mathbf x_0$

Diagonalize A, the chartaristic polynomial is the same one you found the more tradtional way.